# Get name tables, name columns, name datas using .net

Tags: .net, sql-server, conditional-statements

How to get all name tables, name columns, and values in database.

Example i have database "Northwind" in sqlserver 2005.
The name or value may store in collection like System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table or list collection, or other possible accessible. Example: "Customers" as name table, "CompanyName" as name columns, and "" as values in column "Bólido Comidas preparadas".

The reason I wish make this, i want to make script update with condition..

Regard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SqlConnection.GetSchema` method.

[Retrieving Database Schema Information (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively on SQL side you could use system views like this:
SELECT [TABLE_NAME] FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]